# Can Not create a new model and save it into the database. Django rest framework view model set

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a django rest framework project. I am trying to build a view set that overrides the default create method for the ModelViewSet. Right now, I am grabbing all the data that I need to grab from the POSt request and url arguments. I am trying to store them in to a data object and then create a new object in the database based on that same data object.

All the data is correct and setup in the object. How can i make the object savable. I am getting an error and I think it is coming from when I try to save. I am not sure though....

Model View Set - create method:

```
    @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated))
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        namespace = self.kwargs.get('namespace', None)
        path = self.kwargs.get('path', None)
        print(request.user)
        print(request.POST.get('version'))
        print(request.POST.get('namespace'))
        print(request.POST.get('path'))
        print(request.POST.get('value'))
        print(request.user.id)
        if namespace is None and path is None:
            return super().create(request)
        if namespace and path is None:
            data = {
                "person":request.user,
                'version':request.Post.get('version'),
                'namespace':namespace,
                'path':request.Post.get('path'),
                'value':request.Post.get('value'),
                'user_id':request.user.id,
            }
            return super().create(data)
        if namespace and path:
            data = {
                "person":self.request.user,
                'version':self.request.Post.get('version'),
                'namespace':namespace,
                'path':path,
                'value':self.request.Post.get('value'),
                'user_id':self.request.user.id,
            }
            return super().create(data)
```

Model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from owf_framework.people.models import Person

class Preference(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    version = models.BigIntegerField(default=1, null=False)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    namespace = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    value = models.TextField(null=False)
    user_id = models.BigIntegerField(null=False, default=1)
    person = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.namespace

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'preference'
```

Here is the error:

```
AttributeError at /api/v2/preferences/namespace1/
'Request' object has no attribute 'Post'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/preferences/namespace1/
Django Version: 2.2.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Request' object has no attribute 'Post'
Exception Location: C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\request.py in __getattr__, line 414
Python Executable:  C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\jandali\\desktop\\ozone-backend\\ozone-framework-python-server',
 'C:\\Users\\jandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\jandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\jandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\jandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32',
 'C:\\Users\\jandali\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\jandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 10 Jul 2019 04:22:02 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\request.py in __getattr__
            return getattr(self._request, attr) …
▶ Local vars
During handling of the above exception ('WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Post'), another exception occurred:
C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py in wrapped_view
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py in view
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py in dispatch
            response = self.handle_exception(exc) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py in handle_exception
            self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py in dispatch
            response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\jandali\desktop\ozone-backend\ozone-framework-python-server\owf_framework\preferences\views.py in create
                'version':request.Post.get('version'), …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\request.py in __getattr__
            return self.__getattribute__(attr)
```

Comment: What error are you getting? It's hard to help without seeing it.

Comment: just realized i did not put the error: updating post. @AKX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request` object does not have any attribute named `Post`. It can be `request.POST`, or you can also fetch data from `request.data` as well in DRF.

Also, I think there is problem with this line:

```
return super().create(data)
```

Reason is that, when calling a super class, you need to match its method signature. Meaning, you need to pass proper arguments and keyword arguments when calling super class. So it should be like this:

```
return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now, according to the implementation of [**`create`**](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/5c922fb39d798e6eef2796246a578b1b9ca18e10/rest_framework/mixins.py#L16) method, it does not need any parameter named `data` which you have prepared. Because it uses the `request.data` parameter in serializer to create the object.

So I think you can proceed like this:

```
 from rest_framework import status
 from rest_framework.response import 



@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated))
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    namespace = self.kwargs.get('namespace', None)
    path = self.kwargs.get('path', None)
    if namespace is None and path is None:
        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
    if namespace and path is None:
        data = {
            "person":request.user.id,
            'version':request.data.get('version'),
            'namespace':namespace,
            'path':request.data.get('path'),
            'value':request.data.get('value'),
            'user_id':request.user.id,
        }

    if namespace and path:
        data = {
            "person":request.user.id,
            'version':request.data.get('version'),
            'namespace':namespace,
            'path':path,
            'value':request.data.get('value'),
            'user_id':request.user.id,
        }
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Comment: I put the new implimented method that you suggested, but I am still getting the same error which is wierd because it is printing all of the POST data that I tried printed. Why am i gettign this error if i am able to print the POST data.... so confused. Updated post with the error message I am gettting.

Comment: It worked. it got rid o that error, but now I am getting this `HTTP 400 Bad Request
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "person": [
        "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received SimpleLazyObject."
    ]
}` does that mean that instad of pushing `request.user` for `person`, do i just pass in an ID

Comment: it worked. thank you so much! i have been struggling with this for 2 days.